# Stuck with end of life ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04

My old windows xp was giving me lot of problem so I thought of installing ubuntu. I searched for ubuntu and found out that latest released version required 2gb of ram but I have only 1 gb ram. So I searched for old release ubuntu and downloaded 15.04 vivid version and then replaced windows xp with this. Now I came to know that it's end of life for vivid and I am unabel to download and install any software on this ubuntu 15.04. Now I want to use linux lite latest version how can I do that .I don't have any other laptop or pc other than this.

Comment: You might have installed minimal Ubuntu or Lubuntu (light weight flavour of Ubuntu)

Comment: Currently supported versions: 14.04 LTS (till April 2019), 16.04 LTS (till April 2021), 18.04 LTS (till April 2023), and 18.10 (till July 2019). For a lightweight flavour, consider Xubuntu too. Linux Lite is not Ubuntu.

Comment: I suggest that you try current LTS versions of the Ubuntu community flavours Lubuntu and Xubuntu. Lubuntu is ultra light and Xubuntu is medium light. Both work with 1 GB RAM. See this link, [Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

You need to change your apt sources list and change the current Ubuntu domains to *old-releases.ubuntu.com*

After that, you can install `update-manager` and do `do-release-upgrade`.

You will first upgrade to 16.04, and if you want to, from there you can continue to upgrade to 18.04.

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you earned 15 [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). If you have the reputation, don't forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!

Comment: Thank you, with the upvote I got enough to flag as duplicate, would it make sense to delete my answer now?

Comment: You should be able to flag with 15 reputation points only… I think this answer is not necessary and should be removed but someone else gave it an upvote. You ***can*** remove your answer voluntarily but you can also wait until the community decides (I flagged your answer as not an answer which causes it to be reviewed by other [users with 2k rep](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/edit)).

Comment: I see it's not a matter of reputation in my case, I had the app open and flagging only shows three out of five flagging options (and duplicate was not one of them). I'll wait for the community to decide.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia and Ubuntu websites will provide you useful information about maintained *versus* end of life ubuntu versions.
For example this graph ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Version_timeline)) shows that 15.04 is indeed not maintained since 2016:
[image: ubuntu release timelines]

With 1GB RAM and depending on your processor and disk space, you might consider the following flavours of ubuntu 18.04 (the latest Long Term Support version):

- Lubuntu, that is the lightest flavour,
- Xubuntu, a bit heavier than Lubuntu,
- Ubuntu Mate and Ubuntu Budgie, a bit heavier than Xubuntu. If so you would probably meet the *minimal* system requirements, but not the *recommended* system requirements. So it's up to you to give them a try or not. And if you do, try with a live USB first to check it works properly.

Also, I recommend you to use light applications to make your experience smoothier e.g. avoid Libre Office and prefer Abiword and Gnumeric, use Midori or Falkon rather than Chrome (more ideas on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_lightweight_web_browsers))...